# Increase the Performance of Query In Mysql?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

```
SELECT resumeid, FirstName, LastName, Mobile, State, EmailId, Role,
       Skill, Relocation, EmpType, ImmType, TotalExp, Buzzwords 
    from Resume r 
    where DetailsCaptured='Y' 
      and resumeid IN (
               SELECT resumeid FROM Resume_Attachment ra
                   WHERE MATCH (ResumeTextContent)
                   AGAINST ('+"quality"' in boolean mode) ) 
    order by UpdatedDate desc
    limit 100
```

Comment: It's not possible to help you with performance unless you offer many more details. Please read this and then [edit] your question. Especially read the section about query performance. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056

Comment: I would also recommend reading up on INDEXes - I think 2 indexes - 1 on DetailsCaptured and 1 on resumeid - would help. Good luck.

Comment: @user3741598 - MySQL essentially never uses 2 indexes in a single `SELECT` (the outer `SELECT`, in this case).  It just is not efficient enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an *uncorrelated* subquery it is better to use `JOIN` than `IN` or `EXISTS`.  Anyway, `IN ( SELECT ... )`, at least in old versions, had terrible performance.

If this is an attempt at 'lazy eval', it won't work because of the extra test in `WHERE`.

So, Let's just simplify the query:

```
SELECT  resumeid, FirstName, LastName, Mobile, State, EmailId,
        Role, Skill, Relocation, EmpType, ImmType, TotalExp, Buzzwords
    FROM  Resume r
    WHERE  DetailsCaptured='Y'
      AND  MATCH (ResumeTextContent) AGAINST ('+"quality"' in boolean mode) )
    ORDER BY  UpdatedDate desc
    LIMIT  100
```

The Optimizer will

1. Do the `FULLTEXT` lookup *first*; this is fast, but may return more than 100 `resumeid` values;
2. Reach for the rows found in step 1 (I assume  resumeid is the PRIMARY KEY -- It is always helpful to provide SHOW CREATE TABLE.)
3. Ignore any that don't match the rest of the `WHERE` -- DetailsCaptured='Y';
4. Sort (`ORDER BY`)
5. Peel off 100 rows.

You are not going to get faster than that -- unless you can "know" that 'most' rows contain "quality".

Comment: @SergioMontoro -- My answer is in two parts: (1) why `IN` is bad and that `JOIN` is better; (2) how to simplify the query for speed and avoiding `IN/JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

As @O. Jones commented, it is not possible to tell for sure.
Indexing DetailsCaptured might improve your performance, although most of the time will be probably taken by the IN clause and the full-text search.

Try the following alternative.

```
SELECT resumeid, FirstName, LastName, Mobile, State, EmailId, Role, Skill, Relocation, EmpType, ImmType, TotalExp, Buzzwords 
FROM Resume r 
WHERE DetailsCaptured='Y' 
AND EXISTS (SELECT resumeid FROM Resume_Attachment ra WHERE ra.resumeid=r.resumeid AND ResumeTextContent LIKE '%quality%' COLLATE utf8_general_ci) 
ORDER BY UpdatedDate DESC LIMIT 100
```

Comment: If the optimizer chooses to evaluate the subquery 100 times, this formulation will lose badly.  Let's see `EXPLAIN SELECT`.